# SOAP WSDL schemalocation wrong

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to connect to a SOAP service, but I'm getting the error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://jedi:8280/foo/bar/?wsdl&resource=rlapi.xsd'
```

I've looked at the WSDL file, and contains:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:import namespace="http://rl.com/rlapi" schemaLocation="http://jedi:8280/foo/bar?wsdl&resource=rlapi.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

While the url is completely different (http://www.foo.com)

I've tried http://www.foo.com/foo/bar/?wsdl&resource=rlapi.xsd which works fine, but I was wondering if this is something I'm able to set before I get in contact with the people who made the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something you need to discuss with the supplier.

The WSDL defines the location of the service and it should be correct.

It's possible that a development server name has been left in a file somewhere, or that you need to add a host on your local system - anything is possible!

If you REALLY wanted to, you could copy the WSDL file, change the location to what you believe is correct and then load that file instead of the remote one (in order to test your assumptions), but you really need to get in touch with the supplier to ensure that your understanding of the problem is correct.

They will have more information than a random on the internet...